# How to clear a glyph added to my bokeh graph within callback when a new dropdown value is chosen?

Tags: python, graph, bokeh, interactive

I have created side-by-side graphs that link together. When a datapoint is clicked on the first graph, the bar containing that value on the second graph is highlighted. Because bokeh does not have functionality to highlight only 1 selected bar, the solution I used was to create a quad glyph of a different color that is added to the second graph. Example shown below.
[Datapoint clicked on bsps graph to create highlighted glyph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxuWS.png) --> 
[New "Questionnaire" dropdown value clicked, highlighted glyph remains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3oES.png)

```
def callback(attr, old, new):
    highlight_data = []
    # changes month dropdown values based on questionnaire value
    select_month.options = qm[q_select.value]
    #changes patient dropdown values based on questionnaire chosen
    p_select.options = opts[q_select.value]
    # changes visualizations 1 and 2 data
    sample_source.data = ColumnDataSource.from_df(scores.loc[(scores.record_id == p_select.value) & (scores.questionnaire == q_select.value)])
    sample_missing_source.data=ColumnDataSource.from_df(miss.loc[(miss.record_id == p_select.value) & (miss.questionnaire == q_select.value)]) #set this ID equal to initial value of selector

    if '.csv' in new:
        highlight_data = []
        select_month.value = str(0)
        source_t.data = ColumnDataSource.from_df(total_df.loc[(total_df.questionnaire == q_select.value) & (total_df.month == 0)])
    else:
        source_t.data = ColumnDataSource.from_df(total_df.loc[(total_df.questionnaire == q_select.value) & (total_df.month == int(select_month.value))])
    # plot visualization 1 based on new data
    p.title.text='Patient: '+p_select.value+' Diagnosis: '+diagnosis[diagnosis['record_id']==p_select.value]['baseline_dsmiv'].to_string(index=False) + ' Questionnaire: '+q_select.value
    legend_it=[]

    score_vars=[var for var in np.unique(sample_source.data['variable'])]
    missing_vars=[var for var in  np.unique(sample_missing_source.data['variable'])]

def tap_callback(event):
    highlight_data = []
    selected = sample_missing_source.selected.indices
    idx = selected[0]
    row = {c: v[idx] for c, v in sample_missing_source.data.items()}
    select_month.value = str(row['month'])
    source_t.data = ColumnDataSource.from_df(total_df.loc[(total_df.questionnaire == row['questionnaire']) & (total_df.month == int(row['month']))])
    p_t.title.text='Overall Patient Data for Questionnaire: '+ source_t.data['questionnaire'][0] + ", Month: " + str(source_t.data['month'][0])
    p_t.x_range.end = int(source_t.data['total'][0]) + 1
    highlight_data = ColumnDataSource.from_df(total_df.loc[(total_df.questionnaire == row['questionnaire']) & (total_df.month == int(row['month'])) & (total_df.number_questions_answered == int(row['completed']))])
    try:
        p_t.quad(top=int(highlight_data['participant_count']), bottom=0, left=float(highlight_data['number_questions_answered'])-0.5, right=float(highlight_data['number_questions_answered'])+0.5, color="#B3DE69")
    except:
        pass


q_select.on_change('value', callback)
p_select.on_change('value', callback)
select_month.on_change('value',callback)
p.on_event(Tap, tap_callback)
layout1 = column(p_select, q_select, p, digitized_copy)
layout2 = column(select_month, p_t)
curdoc().add_root(row(layout1,layout2))
```

This works to highlight the bar on the second graph in which the datapoint clicked on the first graph lies. However, when I select another "Questionnaire" value from the dropdown, the quad glyph remains on the second graph. I have tried setting highlight_data = [] to reset the data source of the quad glyph,  but this does not work. Any other ideas on how to clear the quad glyph when another "Questionnaire" dropdown value is selected?

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `p_t.quad()` in the callback. Call it once at the top level with an empty data source and just update the data source itself. This way, if you clear the data source the quad will disappear.

Better yet, just reuse the complete data source that has all quads and just use a filter: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html#filtering-data